# Why can't I add a comment to others' questions?

Tags: support, comments

Why can't I add comments to others' questions? I can only answer questions but I need to clarify some more specifically. I see instructions that I should avoid thanking, clarifying and other things in answer field. I see some other people commented on those posts.

For example, I cannot add a comment to this post:

- [While installing Ubuntu, It asked me to allocate something called Swap Space, What exactly is it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83667/while-installing-ubuntu-it-asked-me-to-allocate-something-called-swap-space-wh)

Please help me I want to clarify on swap file topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're new, you don't have reputation points yet to post comments.  When you reach 50 points, you'll be able to do so.  Please see https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment for more information.

The reason for this is to prevent abuse from spammers and bots.  It won't take long to have 50 points - you already have 30! - and you'll be able to post comments.  By the way, there are a lot of privileges that you obtain over time as you accumulate more reputation points.

Comment: This is what clearly makes the difference. An obvious rtfm and offtopic question is answered very constructive and thoroughly with a very friendly attitude. Thank you Kelly and all the others for forming such a helpful community!

Comment: Thank you @Kelley.... Your answer stopped me worrying about my browser. I thought it was my browser fault. Without 50 reputation at least I can thank to people who answered my questions...

Comment: @learner A secondary but also important reason users who haven't yet earned 50 rep cannot comment (and the reason it's probably 50 instead of, say, 10, which is where other spam-related restrictions [are lifted](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/new-user)) is that the site is fundamentally about questions and answers, and comments are secondary. This is true on both main and meta but *especially* on main, since Ask Ubuntu is not a discussion site. If a comment provides a possible solution, it nearly always should be an answer instead (if it's just a link, then *expanded* into an answer).

Comment: And @learner, you are not supposed to say "thank you" in a comment, you "accept" one answer and you can "upvote" any good answer.

Comment: Hi @jokerdino... Since you have marked my question as duplicate. Should i delete this question or whether it will help others while searching with "Why" key word....?